# The total review counter does not increase after a review action is taken unless the page is manually refreshed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

To reproduce:

- Enter one of the [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review)
- Perform a review action (not "Skip") which would ordinarily increment the total review counter
- The review action is logged (and appears in the history tab) but the counter does not increment until the page is refreshed with (e.g. <kbd>F5</kbd>):

  > [image]

Reproduced in:

- FireFox 72.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10,
- Chrome 80.0.3987.106 on Windows 10,
- Edge 44.18362.449.0 on Windows 10,
- Chrome 80.0.3987.87 on Android 10.

Tested with:

- [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close)
- [Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen)
- [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)
- [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits)
- [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts)
- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage)
- [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers)
- [Close Votes (on Meta)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close)

I noticed this while doing some LQP reviews this morning - I'm pretty sure it was working yesterday. I can't test this on any other SE site as I don't have review privileges anywhere other than Stack Overflow.

As another workaround, clicking (or hovering over) the counter or the progress bar shows the badge progress which shows the correct figure:

> [image]

Comment: I noticed the same earlier. I'm using Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 for Mac Sierra. I can also confirm that it was working for me yesterday!

Comment: I saw the same, yesterday evening (Central Europe): Windows 7, FireFox Dev edition (latest update).

Comment: I can confirm this is happening to me - Edge (or Chrome, whatever it's supposed to be called now) from the UK. Mildly annoying.

Comment: Found the bug, fix incoming...

Comment: Duplicate on MSE: [Why is the updated All Time review counter not updated anymore while performing reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343728/284827)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

A small refactor to bring those progress bars up to date with our current CSS (there's not much visually, just some rounded corners, but the change lays some groundwork for better responsiveness and variable contrast modes) broke the JS that dynamically updated their values.  Just a few selector tweaks (and using classes instead of ids) and it's all fixed up.

Comment: I'm guessing that will be rev 2020.2.17.x? I'm still seeing this and just want to make sure rev 2020.2.15.36073 isn't the 'next' build you speak of.

Comment: Also in build rev 2020.2.15.36073 there's no way to mouse over the modal display shown in Wai Ha Lee's last screenshot, since it's not physically connected to the progress bar. Thus, you lose the `:hover` of the parent when you try to mouse over to the child modal element. IIRC this is a bug since you should be able to hover over the badges in that modal to see tooltips on what they mean/how to earn them.

Comment: I can confirm that this (the issue I reported) is fixed as of rev 2020.2.18.36083. The hover behaviour appears to be fixed too - though I couldn't reproduce it on my mobile device due to lack of ability to hover (I always clicked).